# What is the pattern in these shapes?

Tags: pattern, visual

[image]

Source: *Iranian Ph.D. entrance exam 2016*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Nice puzzle! The answer is

> the third one of the four possibilities

because at each stage, to get from one box to the next, you

> take the bottom row, flip it, and put it on the top.

**Example: getting from the first configuration to the second.**

- Start with

  `B B`
  `W W B`
  `W B B`
- > Flip the bottom row to turn `W B B` into `B B W`.
- > Put it on the top to get

  `B B W`
  `B B`
  `W W B`
- Let the top right ball 'drop' to get the second configuration.

**Solution: getting from the fourth configuration to the solution.**

- Start with

  `W B`
  `B W B`
  `B B W`
- > Flip the bottom row to turn `B B W` into `W B B`.
- > Put it on the top to get
  >
  >  `W B B`
  >  `W B`
  >  `B W B`
- Let the top right ball 'drop' to find the solution.